# ¿Cómo cambiar de color un botón de acuerdo a su estado?

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Estoy intentando cambiar de color un botón de acuerdo a su estado los estados que manejo son: 
>   verde = Disponible
>   amarillo = terminando
>   rojo = Ocupado
>   Blanco = fuera de servicio
>   , esta columna estado se encuentra en una base de datos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database")
    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicio WHERE estado";
    $results = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)

    if($row['estado']=="Disponible"){
      echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-verde\"/>";
    }elseif($row['estado']=="Terminando"){
      echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-amarillo\"/>";
     elseif($row['estado']=="Ocupado"){
      echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-rojo\"/>";
    }
     elseif($row['estado']=="Fuera de servicio"){
      echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-blanco\"/>";
    }
   ?>   

  <button type="submit" class="botones">IEQ-524</button>
</html>
```

Comment: falta: un `;` antes de `$query`, un `}` después del bullet amarillo, un `;` antes del primer `if`

Comment: Opino que tu código esta mal
sería así <button link=pagina.php on> color="red"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a proponer una solución más *elegante*  si se quiere. Consiste en lo siguiente:

- Creas un array que tendrá como claves cada estado, y como valor el color correspondiente.
- Basándote en el estado de la fila, obtienes el color.

Esta solución tiene muchas ventajas, no es sólo *elegante*, sino también *práctica*. Supongamos que tengas que decidir entre cientos de colores... ¿vas a poner 100 `if` para obtener el color?  Aplicando este método no necesitarás ningún `if`.

¿Y qué tal del control mayúsculas-minúsculas? En algunos casos en una fila se puede escapar algo como `ocupado` que no es lo mismo que `Ocupado`... haciendo comparaciones una por una se va a emprender un camino muy cuesta arriba.

También, supongamos que necesites manejar colores para otras cosas, que no lleven la palabra `bullet-` delante. Puedes usar el mismo array perfectamente.

Además, podremos controlar también cuando haya un valor que no esté en el array de colores, para asignar en esos casos un color por defecto.

Aquí va el código. Lo he actualizado incorporando las funciones **[`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtolower.php)** en el valor obtenido de la fila y **[`array_change_key_case`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-change-key-case.php)** en las llaves del array. De ese modo no fallará ante posibles valores como `oCupaDo`:

Puedes ver un <kbd>**[DEMO AQUÍ](http://rextester.com/ZKO41227)**</kbd>.

```
<?php 

    /* PHP: Cambiar color de acuerdo al estado : https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/179500/29967 */

    /*Array para determinar el color según el estado*/
    $arrColors=array(
                      "Disponible"=>"verde", 
                      "Terminado"=>"amarillo", 
                      "Ocupado"=>"rojo",
                      "Fuera de Servicio"=>"blanco"
                    );

    /*
        Un array cualquiera para probar nuestro código, 
        estos serías tus valores de la base de datos.
        Pondremos a propósito DATOS divergeNtes para probar
        el control de mayúsculas-minúsculas
    */
    $arrDatos=array( 
                        array("nombre"=>"Pedro",    "estado"=>"OCUPADO"),
                        array("nombre"=>"Santiago", "estado"=>"Disponible"),
                        array("nombre"=>"Juan",     "estado"=>"TermiNado"),
                        array("nombre"=>"Andrés",   "estado"=>"Fuera de Servicio"),
                        array("nombre"=>"Felipe",   "estado"=>"Sin estado")

                   );


    /*
        Una prueba con varios datos
        Si es un solo dato no es necesario el foreach
        sino que se accede al dato directamente
    */

foreach ($arrDatos as $row){
        $estado=strtolower($row["estado"]);
        $color=(isset(array_change_key_case($arrColors)[$estado])) ? array_change_key_case($arrColors)[$estado]  : "default";
        printf('<bullet class="bullet-%s"/>',$color);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```

El código ha leído tres filas de resultados y agregado a cada una el color que le correspondía. Nótese que el último valor no existía en el array de colores y el código le ha asignado `default`.

```
<bullet class="bullet-rojo"/>
<bullet class="bullet-verde"/>
<bullet class="bullet-amarillo"/>
<bullet class="bullet-blanco"/>
<bullet class="bullet-default"/>
```

---

En el contexto que muestras, esta solución se aplicaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database")
    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicio WHERE estado";
    $results = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

    $arrColors=array(
                      "Disponible"=>"verde", 
                      "Terminado"=>"amarillo", 
                      "Ocupado"=>"rojo",
                      "Fuera de servicio"=>"blanco"
                    );

    $estado=strtolower($row["estado"]);
    /*
       Obtendremos el color a través de un ternario
       controlando las posibles claves ausentes y asignado
       en ese caso default  (lo puedes cambiar por otra cosa)
       de ese modo no tendremos más Undefined Index
    */
    $color=(isset(array_change_key_case($arrColors)[$estado])) ? array_change_key_case($arrColors)[$estado]  : "default"; 
    printf('<bullet class="bullet-%s"/>',$color);


   ?>   

  <button type="submit" class="botones">IEQ-524</button>
</html>
```

---

**NOTA:**

Dado que en algunas respuestas he visto sugerencias de agregar los estilos directamente en el contenido, quiero subrayar que hacer esto es considerado hoy día una mala práctica. Se recomienda trasladar los estilos a un archivo .CSS, de forma que el contenido quede independiente. Si nosotros ponemos los estilos directamente en el contenido y luego queremos cambiar algo, vamos a tener que navegar entre cientos o miles de archivos buscando esos estilos para cambiarlos. Mientras que si están en un archivo .CSS, sólo tendríamos que ir a ese archivo y  modificar lo que fuera necesario.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Servicios\Regulacion.php on line 93

Comment: exactamente esta linea printf('<bullet class="bullet-%s"/>',$arrColors[$row["estado"]]);

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris prueba ahora, pero aplicando las dos funciones que controlan los posibles errores debido a que los valores de cadena en PHP son *case sensitive*.  Si en `$row["estado"]`  viene algunos de los estados que no están en `$arrColores` te dará ese mensaje de `Undefined index`... quizá haya que mejorar el código, preguntando si la llave encontrada en `$row["estado"]` existe y si no existe agregar un color por defecto o algo así. El hecho es que si da *Undefined index*  es porque en algún caso el valor no está en el array.

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris he actualizado el código, ahora está blindado contra *Undefined index*. Cuando en `$row` haya un valor no contemplado asignará `default` como color. Puedes cambiar eso por otra cosa, como otro color neutro o lo que desees.

Comment: muchas gracias, cuanto tiempo llevas desarrollando yo estoy apenas en mis inicios que consejo me darias.

Answer (score 1):

Es más cómodo si lo guardas en una variable, una modfiicación sobre la respuesta de @Asdrubal.

```
<?php
  ....

   if($row['estado']=="Disponible") {
       $botones = "bullet-verde";
   } elseif($row['estado']=="Terminando") {
       $botones = "bullet-amarillo";
   } elseif($row['estado']=="Ocupado") {
      $botones = "bullet-rojo";
   } elseif($row['estado']=="Fuera de servicio"){
      $botones = "bullet-blanco";
   }
?>  
<button type="submit" class="<?php echo $botones;?>">IEQ-524</button>
```

Comment: Digo lo mismo que en el otro ejemplo -> Una etiqueta dentro de otra etiqueta que no ha acabado ... me da que esto no va a funcionar.

Comment: @Carmen me gusta tu ayuda pero me muestra este error y no lo veo Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Servicios\Regulacion.php on line 77

Comment: Qué error? el valor de $row['estado'] lo has comprobado? Lo he editado para simplificar los nombres de las clases.

Comment: @Carmen lo siento mucho habia perdido conexion con el internet espera miro

Comment: @Carmen me sigue mostrando el mismo error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Servicios\Regulacion.php on line 77

Comment: es justo esta linea  if($row['estado']=="Disponible") {
       $botones = "bullet-verde";

Comment: La línea anterior no termina en ";" es decir "$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);".

Comment: @Carmen ya esta pero no cambia de color

Comment: Te rellena bien el valor de la clase? Luego ya es cuestión de como tengas el css

Comment: es decir no esta ejecutando la accion

Comment: pero el css si lo tengo como lo debo llamr

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80030/discussion-between-carmen-and-cristian-antonio-trujillo-gris).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo solo seria colocar los condicionales, pero dentro de la clase del boton:

```
<button class="botones <?php if($row['estado']=="Disponible"){
                        echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-verde\"/>";
                    }elseif($row['estado']=="Terminando"){
                        echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-amarillo\"/>";
                    elseif($row['estado']=="Ocupado"){
                        echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-rojo\"/>";
                    }
                    elseif($row['estado']=="Fuera de servicio"){
                        echo "<bullet class=\"bullet-blanco\"/>";
                    }
                ?>  " type="submit">IEQ-524</button>
```

no es lo mas optimo, pero es una buena solucion a tu pregunta, si usaras algun motor de plantilla, te seria de mucha utilidad twig para poder optimizar el codigo y otro seria blade, que es el que trae laravel por defecto

Comment: que es twig ? compañero

Comment: un motor de plantilla, es para poder escribir codigo php mas sencillo sobre html

Comment: @ Asdrubal Hernandez es decir un editor de codigo?

Comment: no, si te interesa, podrias leer su documentacion [aqui](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda estoy adaptanado el codigo a tu respuesta

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris fue un fusto ayudarte

Comment: @Carmen ya corregi, gracias

Comment: Una etiqueta dentro de otro etiqueta que no ha acabado ... me da que esto no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

a mi modo de ver yo le añadirá un campos a la tabla de estado llamado color y en cada botón coloco   style="background-color: #8BC34A;"

```
<?php
                    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database")
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicio WHERE estado";
                    $results = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");

                     $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database")
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM servicio WHERE estado";
                    $results = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");

                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)

                    if($row['estado']=="Disponible"){
                        echo "<bullet style="background-color: $row['color'];" class="$row['color']"/>";
                    }elseif($row['estado']=="Terminando"){
                        echo "<bullet style="background-color: $row['color'];" class="$row['color']"/>";
                    elseif($row['estado']=="Ocupado"){
                        echo "<bullet style="background-color: $row['color'];" class="$row['color']"/>";
                    }
                    elseif($row['estado']=="Fuera de servicio"){
                        echo "<bullet style="background-color: $row['color'];" class="$row['color']"/>";
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Me muestra este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Pruebas2\index.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código , en tu for each de los resultados prueba con este codigo , te recomiendo que en tu base de datos pongas el campo "estado" lo pongas ENUM ('Terminado','Ocupado','Disponible','Fuera de servicio'), y así te funcionara.

```html
 <?php foreach($listado as $p) { ?>

<td class="estado"><?php if ($p->estado == 'Terminado') { ?>
        <span class="label label-warning" style=""><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span></td>
        <?php }else if($p->estado == 'Ocupado'){ ?>
        <span class="label label-danger" ><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span>
        <?php }else if ($p->estado == 'Disponible'){ ?>
                                <span class="label label-success" ><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span>
        <?php }else if ($p->estado == 'Fuera de servicio'){ ?>
                                 <span class="label label-default" ><?php echo $p->estado; ?></span>

                <?php } ?>
                
    <?php } ?>
```